# Rename namespace Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

I'm trying to make like a versions of files. Lets say , I have 15 models in `Account\Models` directory and it’s being called from many files. If I move all the 15 models into `Account\Models\v1` , I have to rename all the namespaces in every files that is related to the models.

What can I do to “automatically” rename the namespace of the models in every files ? Do you have any IDE suggestion that can help with this ? I am using **PhpStorm** by JetBrains and I tried using refactor and it's no success.

Comment: What kind of refactor did you try? A "move" refactor will change namespace i.e. if you select the class name and hit CTRL+M

Comment: Change it manually to make sure you're using the right namespace, since you're not always renaming it.

Comment: Invoke `Refactor | Move` on a class (yes, that actions is context dependant) -- it will move class to a new place and will update namespace where needed. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/move-refactorings.html#d188832e302